# Calling file from different folder / source in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have 2 sources in my project. How can I import a file from MyProject in nest-project-payment?

This is the file structure of my project:

[image: File Structure]

Tried using the following import statement:

```
import { User } from "MyProject/src/entity/User";
```

Comment: In which file do you import user?

Comment: file payment.controller, under nest-project-payment folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { User } from "../../../MyProject/src/entity/User";
```

With `../` you move one folder up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an import like in your example, make the following change to your tsconfig.json file:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@nest-project-payment/*": ["nest-project-payment/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
```